# Is there a way to limit SparkR data frame row into 1000000?

Tags: sparkr

Is there a way to limit SparkR data frame row into 1000000 ? because data file is big is taking time. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try limit? You can use it in a SQL statement or as a SparkR command.